# Can I use an image to be a poster frame for an audio clip on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, avassetexportsession, avmutablecomposition

I'm using AVMutableComposition and AVAssetExportSession to composite several discrete audio clips/files together into a single file, similarly to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247985/composing-video-and-audio-using-avmutablecomposition) but there will be no "video" track. I'd like to give the track some visual appeal using a still image so that when the user plays the clip they don't just see a generic quicktime icon, ideally I'd replace the image with branding or something relevant to the audio content. How would I go about doing it and is there a way to do it without dramatically increasing file size(ie some way to have a really slow framerate or just something so its not generating 30 fps for what is non moving art.) Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1):

[AVAssetWriter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetWriter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) will allow you to create video from a still image. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983882/assetwriterinput-for-making-video-from-uiimages-on-iphone-issues) provides a great example of how to do so.